# Does ngx-cookie-service a complete way to do authentication for Angular Universal apps

Tags: cookies, mean-stack, angular-universal, angular-fullstack, websecurity

I'm building an Angular Universal MEAN (MongoDB, Express, Angular, Node) app, but I'm looking for the correct way to handle security. I know you can't use localStorage with Angular Universal. Is ngx-cookie-service a complete way to handle security, authorization, etc.? Would implementing something like this...

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-cookie-service
```

...or this...

```
https://itnext.io/angular-8-how-to-use-cookies-14ab3f2e93fc
```

Do cookies replace using tokens?

Would it replace code like this in app.js on the backend:

```
    app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
  );
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
  );
  next();
});
```

app.use("/api/posts", postsRoutes);

And this on the backend...

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
    const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_KEY);
    req.userData = { email: decodedToken.email, userId: decodedToken.userId, isAdmin: decodedToken.isAdmin };
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(401).json({ message: "You are not authenticated!" });
  }
};
```

If you have a link to a good example of the code for a simple MEAN stack Angular Univeral app demonstrating the correct way to use cookies, please share. Or perhaps an article with the broad strokes explained if it is a complex explanation. Thank you for your time. It's greatly appreciated.

K

Answer (score 0):

`ngx-cookies` does not provide a 'complete' way to perform authentication, just an easy way to set/get cookies when using angular universal.

In your backend, install and use cookieParser

```
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
app.use(cookieParser());
```

Then, instead of getting your jwt from a custom Authorization header, get it from the cookie

```
const token = req.cookies.authorization.split(" ")[1];
```